# execute multiple Update statement in SQL ignoring error in some queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i created one project in asp.net and c# where i write 10 update queries one after another in SQL Server

that queries were i executed on multiple tables which are similar to each but not exactly similar

there are some update statements are not applicable for some tables,so i want to ignore that error and execute other queries and get final output
is it possible

if yes then please help me

Comment: after a singal query write "GO" statement may be work it

Comment: just put all statement one by one it should work

Comment: Put each Query in its own try catch block (or you can use a loop) and in catch block you can just log which query did not work.This will not just ignore the error as they get logged without causing any effect on execution of other queries.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a stored proc containing all the update statements, each of them encased in a TRY..CATCH block.

This should look like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MyProc]
AS
BEGIN
TRY
    BEGIN
    [STATEMENT 1]
    END
CATCH
    BEGIN
    [DO SOMETHING... OR NOT]
    END

TRY
    BEGIN
    [STATEMENT 2]
    END
CATCH
    BEGIN
    [DO SOMETHING... OR NOT]
    END

TRY
    BEGIN
    [STATEMENT 3]
    END
CATCH
    BEGIN
    [DO SOMETHING... OR NOT]
    END

(...and so on)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this ,

```
    try
{

//get values from text boxes for values you want to update in a string array queryarr
//here it has 4 fields id, name, address and tablename.

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
  try
  {
    string connectionString =
        "server=myown;" +
        "initial catalog=something;" +
        "user id=somebody;" +
        "password=secret";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd =
            new SqlCommand("UPDATE "+queryarr[i,4]+"  SET Name=@NewName, Address=@NewAddress" +
                " WHERE Id=@Id", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", queryarr[i,0]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", queryarr[i,1]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", queryarr[i,2]);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
  }
   catch (SqlException ex)
  {
    //Log the exception but do not display any message.        
  } 

}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //display error message

}
```